# Speeding up this fractal-generating code

Tags: graphics, performance-tuning, parallelization, compile, fractals

I used the code below (which is a sample from [this gist containing more similar code](https://gist.github.com/497210)) in [my answer to my own question about Mandelbrot-like sets for functions other than the simple quadratic on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1107/72) to generate this image:

[image: graphic]

```
cosineEscapeTime = 
 Compile[{{c, _Complex}}, 
  Block[{z = c, n = 2, escapeRadius = 10 \[Pi], maxIterations = 100}, 
   While[And[Abs[z] <= escapeRadius, n < maxIterations], 
    z = Cos[z] + c; n++]; n]]

Block[{center = {0.5527, 0.9435}, radius = 0.1}, 
 DensityPlot[
  cosineEscapeTime[x + I y], {x, center[[1]] - radius, 
   center[[1]] + radius}, {y, center[[2]] - radius, 
   center[[2]] + radius}, PlotPoints -> 250, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]]
```

What could I do to improve the speed/time-efficiency of this code?  Is there any reasonable way to parallelize it?  (I'm running Mathematica 8 on an 8-core machine.)

---

***edit*** Thanks all for the help so far.  I wanted to post an update with what I'm seeing based on the answers so far and see if I get any further refinements before I accept an answer.  Without going to hand-written C code and/or OpenCL/CUDA stuff, the best so far seems to be to use `cosineEscapeTime` as defined above, but replace the `Block[...DensityPlot[]]` with:

```
Block[{center = {0.5527, 0.9435}, radius = 0.1, n = 500},
 Graphics[
  Raster[Rescale@
    ParallelTable[
     cosineEscapeTime[x + I y],
      {y, center[[2]] - radius, center[[2]] + radius, 2 radius/(n - 1)}, 
      {x, center[[1]] - radius, center[[1]] + radius, 2 radius/(n - 1)}], 
   ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"], ImageSize -> n]
 ]
```

Probably in large part because it parallelizes over my 8 cores, this runs in a little under 1 second versus about 27 seconds for my original code (based on `AbsoluteTiming[]`).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use these 3 components: compile, C, parallel computing.

Also to speed up coloring instead of ArrayPlot use

```
Graphics[Raster[Rescale[...], ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]]
```

In such cases Compile is essential. Compile to C with parallelization will speed it up even more, but you need to have a C compiler installed. Note difference for usage of C and parallelization may show for rather greater image resolution and more cores.

```
mandelComp = 
  Compile[{{c, _Complex}}, 
   Module[{num = 1}, 
    FixedPoint[(num++; #^2 + c) &, 0, 99, 
     SameTest -> (Re[#]^2 + Im[#]^2 >= 4 &)]; num], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   Parallelization -> True];

data = ParallelTable[
   a + I b, {a, -.715, -.61, .0001}, {b, -.5, -.4, .0001}];

Graphics[Raster[Rescale[mandelComp[data]], 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"], ImageSize -> 800, PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

[image]

This is just a prototype - you can figure out a better coloring. Another way is to use LibraryFunction - we have Mandelbrot built in:

```
mlf = LibraryFunctionLoad["demo_numerical", "mandelbrot", {Complex}, 
   Integer];
n = 501; samples = 
 Table[mlf[x + I y], {y, -1.25, 1.25, 2.5/(n - 1)}, {x, -2., .5, 
   2.5/(n - 1)}];
colormap = 
  Function[If[# == 0, {0., 0., 0.},  Part[r, #]]] /. 
   r -> RandomReal[1, {1000, 3}];
Graphics[Raster[Map[colormap, samples, {2}]], ImageSize -> 512]
```

[image]

Now, if you have a proper NVIDIA graphics card you can do some GPU computing with CUDA or OpenCL. I use OpenCL here because I got the source (from documentation btw):

```
Needs["OpenCLLink`"]

src = "
  __kernel void mandelbrot_kernel(__global mint * set, float zoom, \
float bailout, mint width, mint height) {
     int xIndex = get_global_id(0);
     int yIndex = get_global_id(1);
     int ii;

     float x0 = zoom*(width/3 - xIndex);
     float y0 = zoom*(height/2 - yIndex);
     float tmp, x = 0, y = 0;
     float c;

     if (xIndex < width && yIndex < height) {
         for (ii = 0; (x*x+y*y <= bailout) && (ii < MAX_ITERATIONS); \
ii++) {
              tmp = x*x - y*y +x0;
              y = 2*x*y + y0;
              x = tmp;
          }
          c = ii - log(log(sqrt(x*x + y*y)))/log(2.0);
          if (ii == MAX_ITERATIONS) {
              set[3*(xIndex + yIndex*width)] = 0;
              set[3*(xIndex + yIndex*width) + 1] = 0;
              set[3*(xIndex + yIndex*width) + 2] = 0;
          } else {
              set[3*(xIndex + yIndex*width)] = ii*c/4 + 20;
              set[3*(xIndex + yIndex*width) + 1] = ii*c/4;
              set[3*(xIndex + yIndex*width) + 2] = ii*c/4 + 5;
          }
      }
  }
  ";

MandelbrotSet = 
  OpenCLFunctionLoad[src, 
   "mandelbrot_kernel", {{_Integer, _, "Output"}, "Float", 
    "Float", _Integer, _Integer}, {16, 16}, 
   "Defines" -> {"MAX_ITERATIONS" -> 100}];

width = 2048;
height = 1024;
mem = OpenCLMemoryAllocate[Integer, {height, width, 3}];

res = MandelbrotSet[mem, 0.0017, 8.0, width, height, {width, height}];

Image[OpenCLMemoryGet[First[res]], "Byte"]
```

[image]

References:

[Fractals CDF paper](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/uses-examples/MandelbrotAndJuliaSets/MandelbrotAndJuliaSets.cdf)

[Compile to C](http://wolfram.com/xid/04z8qdup2d6j1yie-je7ul7)

[LibraryFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/LibraryLink/tutorial/Numerical.html)

[OpenCL](http://wolfram.com/xid/0isq3flowdud5n74bny881he6-fpfe3h)

[Demonstrations](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=mandelbrot)

Comment: Great answer. I'd upvote but I'm out of votes for today.

Comment: Thank you, Mike, your answer is great too! This is all compiled from bits of Documentation. I'll post links too.

Comment: If any answer is the "right" one (of which all of these are), this would be the one. Beautifully demonstrates usage of every concept mentioned, *plus* it has references to the documentation.

Comment: I played with this a little using `AbsoluteTiming[Graphics[Raster[Rescale@ParallelTable[...],ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]]]` and it seems like your `FixedPoint[]` formulation of the escape-time function is slower and produces different results than my original `While[]` formulation, and adding `, CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True` inside the `Compile[]` of my `While[]` version doesn't make any significant difference.  As you suggested, the `Graphics[Raster[Rescale@...]]` formulation is *much* faster than `DensityPlot[]`.

Comment: With further experimentation, the `FixedPoint[]` version does yield the same results as my `While[]` version (I missed something that caused it not to before), but it is still about 20% slower than the `While[]` version.

Comment: @Isaac My guess is that Parallelization and C would start to show advantage for the larger image sizes and more cores present. I just wanted to share different approaches documented in M. Thanks for trying these out ;-)

Comment: @Isaac at one point I wasted a day or so trying to find the fastest way to obtain the mandelbrot set. The fastest I could do was `While[(iters < maxiter) && (Abs@z < 2),iters++;z = z^2 + c]` compiled to C, and this was a bit faster than `FixedPoint`, `Nest` and other similar approaches. ie, I found the same as you.

Comment: Strange, `Graphics[Raster[Rescale[...]]]` returns a white image in Mathematica 10 on OS X. `ArrayPlot[Reverse@...]` works fine.

Answer (score 33):

This might be an excellent candidate for `ParallelTable`;

```
MakeFractal[f_, nx_, ny_, {cx_, cy_}, {rx_, ry_}] := Module[{pts},
  DistributeDefinitions[nx, ny, cx, cy, rx, ry, f];
  pts = ParallelTable[f[x + I y], 
    {x, cx - rx, cx + rx, (2 rx)/nx},
     {y, cy - ry, cy + ry, (2 ry)/ny}];
  ArrayPlot[Reverse@pts, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
  ]
```

Note that evaluation time is very fast, but plotting isn't.

You may wish to alternatively adjust the `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` parameters of DensityPlot. `MaxRecursion` controls how far deep Mathematica goes for each plot point to determine the function value to use.

Too high of a value for `MaxRecursion` can lead to very long evaluation, especially with fractals.

Another way to help speed is to use `CompilationTarget->"C"` and `RuntimeOptions->Speed`. These sometimes provide a (small) speedup.

---

Here's some timing values (Note your value of PlotPoints->250 is a bit excessive):

```
(* 4.05 seconds on my machine *)
AbsoluteTiming[
 Block[{center = {0.5527, 0.9435}, radius = 0.1},
  DensityPlot[cosineEscapeTime[x + I y],
   {x, center[[1]] - radius, center[[1]] + radius},
   {y, center[[2]] - radius, center[[2]] + radius},
   PlotPoints -> 120, MaxRecursion -> 2,
   AspectRatio -> 1, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]]
 ]

(* 2.07 seconds on my machine *)
AbsoluteTiming[
 pts = ParallelTable[
   cosineEscapeTime[x + I y], {x, xc - r, xc + r, (2 r)/nx}, {y, 
    yc - r, yc + r, ( 2 r)/ny}];
 ListDensityPlot[pts, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
 ]
```

And individually for the `ParallelTable` approach:

```
(* 0.753 seconds on my machine *)
AbsoluteTiming[
 pts = ParallelTable[
    cosineEscapeTime[x + I y], {x, xc - r, xc + r, (2 r)/nx}, {y, 
     yc - r, yc + r, ( 2 r)/ny}];
 ]

(* 1.397 seconds on my machine *)
AbsoluteTiming[
 ListDensityPlot[pts, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
 ]
```

Using ArrayPlot as Mr.Wizard suggests is much faster:

```
(* 0.233 seconds on my machine *)
AbsoluteTiming[
 ArrayPlot[Reverse@pts,
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"
  ]
 ]
```

As you can see, plotting takes up a rather large amount of time.

Comment: Am I giving up anything significant in plotting an explicit table of points rather than having Mathematica/DensityPlot figure out for me dynamically which points to plot?

Comment: @Isaac: Well, you have to play around with the number of points which is a downside. In the other version you can just adjust `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` and Mathematica "knows" where to evaluate next. Otherwise, you have the same "formatting" options that `DensityPlot` has

Comment: You guys should try Raster here: Graphics[Raster[..., ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]] With ColorFunction the Raster may be the fastest.

Answer (score 15):

Many plots can be speeded up by pre-generating the data set you want and then plotting the resulting list. In any case, it's not coincidence that `Table` and `Plot` have similar syntax, only that `Plot` does additional things like finding out the range to be displayed, the interpolation strength, and so forth. If you're already sure what kind of picture you want to get out, you may want to generate the data set by hand, like mentioned by Mike.

In your case, you can add just a few characters to the block part,

```
Block[{center = {0.5527, 0.9435}, radius = 0.1, data},
    data = ParallelTable[
        cosineEscapeTime[x + I y],
        {x, center[[1]] - radius, center[[1]] + radius, 2 radius/250},
        {y, center[[2]] - radius, center[[2]] + radius, 2 radius/250}
    ];
    ListDensityPlot[
        data,
        AspectRatio -> 1,
        ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"
    ]
]
```

This speeds up the process by more than an order of magnitude for me, and requires significantly less memory than the automatic plot. However, there's no interpolation in tricky corners of the plot here, so if you want a larger image you may want to change the parameters, i.e. decrease step size etc.

Comment: I'd like to second this.  To explain a bit more: `DensityPlot` assumed a more or less smooth function (which this isn't), and tries to figure out where it need to sample more points for sufficient detail.  Relevant options are `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`.  Both `DensityPlot` and `ListDensityPlot` will interpolate between sampled points, which can again be slow.  I'd suggest using an `Image` instead of `ListDensityPlot`.

Answer (score 11):

On version 7 you will need to use `DistributeDefinitions`:

```
{xc, yc} = {0.5527, 0.9435};
r = 0.1;
nx = 350;
ny = 350;

DistributeDefinitions[nx, ny, xc, yc, r];

pts = ParallelTable[
        cosineEscapeTime[x + I y],
        {x, xc - r, xc + r, (2 r)/nx},
        {y, yc - r, yc + r, (2 r)/ny}
      ];
```

For faster plotting try using `ArrayPlot`:

```
ArrayPlot[Reverse@pts, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

Or better still as Vitaliy recommends:

```
Graphics[Raster[Rescale@pts, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]]
```

Comment: Welcome to the party :)

Comment: With ColorFunction the fastest will be Raster: Graphics[Raster[..., 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]]