# Poor rendering of fractals

Tags: graphics, configuration, fractals

Could someone explain why I get those ugly graphics ..

[image]

..trying to use fractals in mathematica 8 ?

I'd also like to know if it is possible to draw 2D fractals in Mathematica

---

My configuration is:

- Windows 7 64 bits
- Intel Pentium P600
- RAM 4Go
- ATI Mobility Radeon HD5470

Comment: Does this only happen when rendering the fractal or with any 3D graphics in Mathematica?  Have you upgraded your graphics drivers to their latest version?  If you haven't, it's something worth doing.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104

Answer (score 12):

I think the lower quality you see has to do with the downscaling of the image. It is generated at 512x512 pixels which you can check if you right mouse click on the image, but it isn't displayed that way. So, if I change this to:

```
OpenCLFractalRender3D[ImageSize -> 512]
```

I get

[image: Mathematica graphics].

As to your second question: of course you can use Mathematica to generate 2D fractals. It has a [rich set of drawing primitives](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Graphics.html). Examples can be found in the manual (for instance, [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Compile/tutorial/Efficiency.html)).

Comment: When I do this command, I get nothing -- just *"OpenCLFFractalRender3D[ImageSize->512"* written, ideas why? How to get the picture?

Comment: @hhh This may be an installation/drfiver/graphics card issue. Currently, I have troubles running this command in Mathematica 9. In v8, installed on the same PC, everything is OK. You may try some of the installation guides in the CUDAlink tutorial.

Comment: Additionally, you have to run ``Needs["CUDALink`"]`` before that command. What helped me in a reinstallation of the CUDA resources using `CUDAResourcesInstall[Update -> True]`.

Answer (score 12):

You can certainly draw 2D fractals, eg the Mandelbrot set

```
ClearAll[mnd]
mnd = Compile[{{m, _Integer}, {n, _Integer}, {steps, _Integer},
{maxiter, _Integer}, {xmax, _Real}},
   Block[{z, c, iters = 0},
    z = c = -xmax + 2.*xmax*n/steps - 0.5 + I*(-xmax + 2.*xmax*m/steps);
    While[(iters < maxiter) && (Abs@z < 2),
     iters++;
     z = z^2 + c
     ];
    Sqrt[iters/maxiter]
    ],
   {{z, _Complex}, {c, _Complex}}
   ];

ListContourPlot[
 Table[
  mnd[m, n, 200, 200, 1],
  {m, 1, 200}, {n, 1, 200}
  ],
 Frame -> False
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or the Hofstadter butterfly

```
ClearAll[matrix];
matrix[p_,q_,nu_:0]:=Module[
    {sigma},
    sigma=p/q;
    N@SparseArray[
        {{m_,m_} -> 2Cos[2Pi*m*p/q + nu], {i_,j_}/;Abs[i-j] == 1 -> 1},{q,q}]]

ClearAll[attachsigma]
attachsigma[sigma_,lst_]:={sigma,#}&/@lst

fracs = Table[p/q, {q, 2, 80}, {p, 2, q}] // Flatten // 
   DeleteDuplicates;
pq = {Numerator@#, Denominator@#} & /@ fracs;
(ens = Eigenvalues[#] & /@ (matrix[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ pq);) // Timing
pts = Flatten[#, 1] &@MapThread[attachsigma, {fracs, ens}];
plot = Graphics[
  {PointSize[0.001], Point[pts]},
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  ImageSize -> Full
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answers. (sorry about the link, i can't post images yet because i'm new)

Comment: I am not sure if this is complete Hofstadter butterfly? :)

Answer (score 4):

And if disk or screen space is at a premium, have a look at Stephan Leibbrandt´s lovely Mandelbrot oneliner using just 130 characters:

[Oneliner Competition 2011](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/01/the-2011-mathematica-one-liner-competition/)

[Notebook of the winning entries... quite handy to view with the CDF plugin](http://blog.wolfram.com/data/uploads/2011/11/OneLinerWinners2011.nb).

Comment: Excellent. I especially enjoyed William Wu's entry...