# Plotting large datasets

Tags: plotting, memory

I have a lot of data (e.g., 64x8192), to plot and it consumes too much memory (more than 2 GB) causing Mathematica to return "no memory available".

For example,

```
lst = Table[Sin[x^2 + y^2], {x, 2^7}, {y, 2^13}];
ListDensityPlot[lst]
```

Is there any way to cope with it?

Comment: Strongly related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140/121

Comment: While [this related thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7142/89) does not deal with downsampling and memory consumption, it allows you to display only a smaller area of a large plot and easily pan through/zoom in/out of the whole.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

*Scroll to the end for the latest edit.*

If you really want all the points in a large data set, I'd use a more basic display method:

Let's say the matrix of data is `m`, then do this (assuming the entries `m[[i, j]]` are real numbers):

```
Image[Rescale[m]]
```

This will make one pixel for each data point without trying to do any interpolation as is the default in density plots.

**Edit**

As suggested in the comment, here is a comparison of the timings:

```
(* A test matrix with random entries between 0 and 1: *)
m = RandomReal[1, {300, 300}];
Timing@Image[m]
```

[image: fast]

```
Timing@ListDensityPlot[m, MaxPlotPoints -> 1000]
```

[image: slow]

So the `ListDensityPlot` is several orders of magnitude slower than my `Image` suggestion. This conclusion seems to be almost *independent* of the choice for `MaxPlotPoints`.

With the `Image` approach, it is no problem to create extremely large images (say  $5000\times 5000$). I would not advise using `ListDensityPlot` for anything like this.

If you want a colored output, just use `Colorize` as follows:

```
m = RandomReal[1, {300, 300}];

Timing[plot = Colorize[Image[m], ColorFunction -> "LakeColors"]]
```

[image: colorized]

**Edit 2**

The final question would be, how to re-create the frame and ticks that you get from `ListDensityPlot` and its relatives. Let's assume that the range of `x` and `y` values corresponding to the matrix dimensions of `m` are $x \in [0, 2]$ and $y\in[0, 3]$, respectively. Then you get the standard display for the `plot` we just created as follows:

```
xmin = 0;
ymin = 0;
xmax = 2;
ymax = 3;
Graphics[Inset[
  Show[plot, AspectRatio -> Full], 
  {xmin, ymin}, 
  {0, 0}, 
  {xmax - xmin, ymax - ymin}], 
 PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: framed plot]

The trick here is to align the bottom left corner `{0,0}` of the `Image` to the lower coordinate limits of the `PlotRange` I chose for the `Graphics`, and then (using the fourth argument of `Inset`) to stretch the image to fit exactly into that `PlotRange`. The content is only stretchable this way if you show it with the option `AspectRatio -> Full`.

**Edit 3**

For completeness, here is the example matrix given in the question, constructed in a slightly modified way to make its entries lie between `0` and `1`. Here, `Rescale` turns out to be very slow when applied to an array of exact numbers, so I speed things up by adding `N[]` during the construction of the matrix. Thanks to MichaelE2 for pointing this out in the comment. The matrix construction uses `Outer` and automatically threads `Sin` over lists in its argument.

In this construction, the `x` coordinate is represented by `Range[2^7]` and the `y` coordinate by `Range[2^13]` - if you switch these then the plot will have the axes switched. The `Reverse` below is needed to have the vertical axis pointing up:

```
s = Sin[Outer[Plus, N[Reverse[Range[2^13]]^2], N[Range[2^7]^2]] ];
plot = Colorize[Image[s], ColorFunction -> "LakeColors"];

xmin = 1;
ymin = 1;
xmax = 2^7;
ymax = 2^13;
Graphics[Inset[
  Show[plot, AspectRatio -> Full], {xmin, ymin}, {0, 0}, {xmax - xmin, 
   ymax - ymin}], PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}, 
 Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: sin 2d]

The point of this example is to show how much more detail we get with this approach, compared to the slower `ListDensityPlot`.

**Alternative: ArrayPlot**

I mentioned using `Rescale` earlier because the arguments to `Image` have to be in the unit interval to be mapped onto the grayscale range from white to black. This grayscale can later be colorized too. It's important to keep this fact in mind: matrix entries that fall outside the interval $[0, 1]$ will not lie in  the range where the grayscale varies and will therefore appear at the same extreme grayscale (or color afte using `Colorize`).

Once we add the rescaling and the frame ticks, the `Image` approach de-facto  converges to the built-in function `ArrayPlot`. This is another easy-to-use way of getting a fast plot of a large matrix. You would use it like this: `ArrayPlot[m, ColorFunction -> "LakeColors", DataReversed -> True]`. I just tried this with the last example matrix, and it works nicely.

**One more observation**

According to [this linked answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109/245), when using `ColorFunction`, `ArrayPlot` isn't as fast as the direct creation of a `Raster` image. The solution proposed there is not `Image` as I used here, but instead something like this: `Graphics[Raster[Rescale[...], ColorFunction -> "LakeColors"]]`

To try this with my frame construction, you would have to write it like this (where `s` is the same as defined in **Edit 3**):

```
xmin = 1;
ymin = 1;
xmax = 2^7;
ymax = 2^13;
Graphics[Inset[
  Show[
   Graphics[Raster[s, ColorFunction -> "LakeColors"]], 
   AspectRatio -> Full, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0], 
  {xmin, ymin}, 
  {0, 0},
  {xmax - xmin, ymax - ymin}
 ], 
 PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}, 
 Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1
]
```

When I wrap this in `Timing` or `AbsoluteTiming`, I indeed get even lower values. *However*, I don't really believe those values because the actual time it takes for the plot to appear in the notebook is noticeably slower with this last approach. Nevertheless, I think it's worth including this here.

**More timing results**

To test these display methods with the Mandelbrot set of [this linked answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109/245),  I did a different timing measurement based on recording the absolute time before and after the image/graphic has been displayed. Here is the code to prepare the pictures:

```
mandelComp = 
  Compile[{{c, _Complex}}, 
   Module[{num = 1}, 
    FixedPoint[(num++; #^2 + c) &, 0, 99, 
     SameTest -> (Re[#]^2 + Im[#]^2 >= 4 &)]; num], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   Parallelization -> True];

data = ParallelTable[
   a + I b, {a, -.715, -.61, .0001}, {b, -.5, -.4, .0001}];

rc = Rescale[mandelComp[data]];
```

Now the timing tests (not showing the images that are generated):

```
a1 = AbsoluteTime[]; Graphics[
 Raster[rc, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"], ImageSize -> 800, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0]

a2 = AbsoluteTime[]

a2 - a1

(* ==> 6.878487 *)
```

This is pretty slow. Compare this to the `Image` approach:

```
a1 = AbsoluteTime[]; Colorize[Image[rc, ImageSize -> 800], 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]

a2 = AbsoluteTime[]

a2 - a1

(* ==> 1.119959 *)
```

This is much faster. The `ArrayPlot` method is twice as slow as the last result, but still faster than the `Raster` method:

```
a1 = AbsoluteTime[];
ArrayPlot[rc, ImageSize -> 800, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]

a2 = AbsoluteTime[]

a2 - a1

(* ==> 2.089126 *)
```

Therefore, my conclusion is: when in doubt, go with `Image`.

**Edit (19 June 2014)**

It seems useful to wrap the conclusion of this answer in a general-purpose function that works similarly to `ListDensityPlot` but is based on directly creating an `Image` from the data:

```
Clear[listPixelPlot] ;
Options[listPixelPlot] = {Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {}, 
   ColorFunction -> "LakeColors" ,
   AspectRatio -> 1, DataRange -> All , ImageSize -> Automatic, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotRangeClipping -> True};

listPixelPlot[array_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module [{field, plot, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, 
   dataRange = OptionValue[DataRange], 
   plotRange = 
    Replace[OptionValue[PlotRange], 
     Full | All | Automatic -> {Automatic, Automatic}], range},
  field = Reverse@Transpose[array] ;
  {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}} = range = If[
     MatrixQ[dataRange] ,
     Reverse[dataRange],
     Map [ {0 , #} &, Dimensions[array] ]
     ] ;
  plot = Colorize[Image[Rescale[N[field] ] ] , 
    ColorFunction -> OptionValue[ColorFunction]] ;
  Graphics[
   Inset[
    Show [plot, AspectRatio -> Full] , {xmin, ymin} , {0, 
     0} , {xmax - xmin, ymax - ymin}],
   PlotRange -> 
    Table[plotRange[[i]] /. Full | All | Automatic -> range[[i]], {i, 
      2}],
   Sequence @@ 
    Map[# ->  OptionValue[#] & , {Frame, FrameLabel, ImageSize, 
      AspectRatio, PlotRangeClipping}]]
  ]
```

This function takes some of the same options that `ListDensityPlot` or `ArrayPlot` accept (see `Options[`). With the Mandelbrot test data `rc` from above, you would call this function (and test its timing) as follows:

```
a1 = AbsoluteTime[];
listPixelPlot[rc, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", ImageSize -> 800]

a2 = AbsoluteTime[];

a2 - a1

(* ==> 1.679611 *)
```

This is only slightly slower than the fastest result above. The reason is simply that in this function the argument `array` is *always* processed by `Rescale` before converting it to an `Image`. To make sure `Rescale` sees a packed array of machine numbers, the core of the function reads `Image[Rescale[N[field] ] ]`. A lot of the code deals merely with option handling. It can be extended to provide additional options.

Comment: You've solve my problem more than I can expect, and you go further than kguler. I really enjoy your advice although I have accepted kguler's answer.

Comment: @Jens, Not only speed and efficiency but also the looks are uncomparably nicer with `Image`; you may consider posting an image to highlight this additional advantage using, say, a variation of the OP's example data `m= Table[Sin[x^2 + y^2], {x, 2^10}, {y, 2^10}]; Image[m]//Colorize`. (+++1 needless to say)

Comment: I really enjoy your solution. But I've met some other problem. Since I cannot paste images in the comment, please compare dt = Table[Log10[Abs@Sin[0.2 x] Exp[-y^2]], {x, 100}, {y, 10}];ListDensityPlot[dt, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["GreenPinkTones"], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True, MaxPlotPoints -> 1000, 
 ImageMargins -> 5] and img = Colorize[Image[dt], 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData["GreenPinkTones"]];Graphics[Inset[
  Show[img, AspectRatio -> Full], {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Frame -> True]. Any advice?

Comment: @yulinlinyu Yes - the data in `td` have to be rescaled first before they can be used in `Image`. The numbers always have to be between `0` and `1` for this to work. So you could in this case replace `td` by `Rescale[td]`. Or even better, prepare the data so they are rescaled to begin with, as I did in the last example I posted. Then the image will show the color range as expected. Since the x axis has only 10 data, the colors won't look smooth in `Image`, but the point is that for _large_ dimensions you won't notice this discreteness.

Comment: Yes, it is so cool. Thank you very much! I love SE because I can always find many cool and clever way for my problem.

Comment: What about a array contains unevenly spaced data points, for example {{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2}...}? Do you have any idea of how to deal with this?

Comment: Re Edit 3: `Rescale` is slow because `s` is not packed.  Try `s = Rescale@Sin[Outer[Plus, Reverse[N@Range[2^13]]^2, N@Range[2^7]^2]];` and compare timings.  (Sorry for the late comment.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ah yes, great catch. I can't count the number of times this has bitten me before... usually I look for this pitfall when  something slows down so much, but this time I just resorted to manual tuning.

Comment: Wow, your tool is great, saves my day! But I still have questions: Why `ListDensityPlot` is so so slow? I have a data like `{{x,y,z},...}` which has 403229 points. I just have no patient to wait the result come out. Even I used MaxPlotPoints->5, the result can't come out in a reasonable time and I gave it up! What is the essential difference between `ListDensityPlot` and `image`. My friend just showed me how matplotlib's pcolormesh done it in a few second, and I know pcolor is several orders slower than pcolormesh. Is pcolor correspond to ListDensityPlot and pcolormesh correspond to image?

Comment: Also, have you got any ideas to deal with  xslittlegrass's comment?

Comment: @matheorem The big difference is interpolation. But I don't have any way to generalize the approach in this answer to non-uniformly spaced data.

Comment: Hi, @Jens. But I doubt it. Because setting `Interpolation->0` doesn't make plotting significantly faster. Actually `Timing@ListDensityPlot[RandomReal[1, {300, 300}], InterpolationOrder -> 0]` is even two times slower than `AbsoluteTiming@ListDensityPlot[RandomReal[1, {300, 300}]]` on my computer

Comment: @matheorem That's true, and I have no idea because I don't know how it works internally.

Answer (score 15):

`ListDensityPlot` uses all the points in the dataset. You can set `MaxPlotPoints` option to control downsampling:

```
  ListDensityPlot[lst, MaxPlotPoints -> 1000]
```

[image]

Memory consumption using `MaxMemoryUsed`:

```
 miu0 = MaxMemoryUsed[]
 lst = Table[Sin[x^2 + y^2], {x, 2^7}, {y, 2^13}];
 usg0 = MaxMemoryUsed[] - miu0
 miu1 = MaxMemoryUsed[]
 ListDensityPlot[lst, MaxPlotPoints -> 1000];
 usg1 = MaxMemoryUsed[] - miu1
 miu2 = MaxMemoryUsed[]
 ListDensityPlot[lst];
 usg2 = MaxMemoryUsed[] - miu2
```

Incremental memory consumption:

```
 {usg0, usg1, usg2}
 (* ==> {96 881 240, 447 831 576, 3 243 923 016} *)
```

That is, the input data and plotting with `MaxPlotPoints->1000` should not trigger `Out Of Memory` issues, while without the explicit `MaxPlotPoints` producing the plot consumes more than 3G of additional memory beyond what is needed for holding the input data.

Comment: I think this is just I want!

Comment: @yulinlinyu, thank you for the accept.

Comment: @yulinlinyu, you can change your mind about which answer to accept any time; and if this were my question i would choose Jens's answer. Try, for example, `lst = Table[Sin[x^2 + y^2], {x, 2^10}, {y, 2^10}]; Image[lst]//Colorize` to see why.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. The code in your advice is so amazing that I cannot imagine it before.

Answer (score 10):

You can use a `Span` to only use some of the points.  E.g.

```
lst[[;; ;; 10, ;; ;; 10]]
```

will take every 10th point (in each dimension).  This is of course a rather crude way of down sampling.

Comment: This is really a easiest way!

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to deal with this issue is to reduce the number of points in your plot to a manageable level.

Computer monitors have only so many pixels and human eyes have only so much resolution. Having this many points in a graphic will not convey more information or make it look clearer.

The example function you gave, Sin[x^2+y^2] cannot be reasonably made into a graphic over the range you provided. The structure of the function wouldn't be noticeable.

Comment: I use Sin[x^2+y^2] here is just to generate a large list. Actually, the list comes from very complicated numerical calculations.

Comment: If your function is smooth enough to make a sensible plot with an enormous amount of data points, it will be smooth enough to make a good looking plot with a much smaller number of points. Try re-sampling the data set so that it is manageable.

Comment: Not quite true. Resolution of 1600x1200 gives of order 10^6 points. If your are to make a plot with about 5x10^5 points having 1 point per pixel, it will cause you plotting problems with information being not oversampled.