# Fractal plotting for the Collatz fractal

Tags: plotting, graphics, fractals

I have the following equation:

```
f[z_] := 1/4 (2 + 7 z - (2 + 5 z) Cos[Pi*z])
```

I want to map this on the imaginary plane such that if it converges under iterations of the function then it is plotted. I would like to then color this in a Mandelbrot type way. How would I go about plotting this?

The goal is to explore the fractal mentioned [here](http://yozh.org/2012/01/12/the_collatz_fractal/).

This is the type of image i'm trying to produce with the ability to zoom in to particular points.

[image: Goal]

Comment: Have you seen [Speeding up this fractal-generating code](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104/speeding-up-this-fractal-generating-code)

Comment: Have you seen [MandelbrotSetPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MandelbrotSetPlot.html)

Comment: Have you seen [Mandelbrot Set](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MandelbrotSet.html)

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance blase, how may I help you? Maybe I can program the whole thing for you?

Comment: Tweak as needed: `DensityPlot[-Length[FixedPointList[Function[z, (2 + 7 z - (2 + 5 z) Cos[Pi z])/4], x + I y, 100, SameTest -> (Abs[#2] > 25. &)]], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -1, 1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> (RGBColor[0, 0, #] &), PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: I'm always at a loss with these pictures, about what is being plotted.  Nathaniel Johnston [writes](http://www.njohnston.ca/2009/06/the-collatz-conjecture-as-a-fractal/) that the black portions of the plot are areas where the orbit is bounded (Check out the `Orbit` function [here](http://thales.math.uqam.ca/~rowland/packages/ListTricks.m)).  But what is the color in the rest of the plot based on?

Comment: "but with each color representing the number of iterations required before a point is declared to not be a member of the Collatz set."

So when provable not in the set show steps takes to prove if not have a halting criteria which is the uniform background color.

Comment: The snippet I gave is essentially a naive escape-time algorithm implementation. As noted, adjust stuff as needed (e.g. `PlotPoints`, `MaxRecursion`, `ColorFunction`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way of coding the iterations may be defined as follows. The function `CollatzFractal01[z0]` returns a list `{Abs[z],iter}`, where `Abs[z]` is the final value of `z`, and `iter` is the number of iterations required to escape the bound of `Abs[z]>200`. Use compilation and parallelisation for speed.

```
CollatzFractal01 = Compile[{{z0, _Complex, 0}},
   Module[{iter = 0, max = 3000, z = z0},
      While[iter++ < max, 
         If[Abs[z = (2 + 7 z - (2 + 5 z) Cos[Pi z])/4] > 200., Break[]]];
      {Abs[z], iter}],
   CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True, 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
```

Generate a table of locations in the complex plane with `ParallelTable`.

```
d = ParallelTable[i + I*j, {j, -0.5, 0.5, 0.001}, {i, 0.3, 2.5, 0.001}];
```

`Graphics[Raster[...]]` can be faster than `ArrayPlot[...]`. This plot shows the final `Abs[z]`.

```
Graphics[Raster[
   Rescale[Log[Log[CollatzFractal01[d][[All, All, 1]] + 1.] + 1.]],
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["FallColors", 1 - #] &)],
   ImageSize -> 600, Background -> Black]
```

[image: CollatzFractal01 Abs z]

This plot shows the number of iterations.

```
Graphics[Raster[
   Rescale[Log[Log[CollatzFractal01[d][[All, All, 2]] + 1.] + 1.]],
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow", #^0.5] &)],
   ImageSize -> 600, Background -> Black]
```

[image: CollatzFractal01 iter]

Slightly redefining your original equation gives more "interesting" plots, with far more structure. However, the calculation time increases substantially.

```
CollatzFractal02 = Compile[{{z0, _Complex, 0}},
   Module[{iter = 0, max = 3000, z = z0},
      While[iter++ < max, 
         If[Abs[z = (1 + 4 z - (1 + 2 z) Cos[Pi z])/4] > 200., Break[]]];
      {Abs[z], iter}],
   CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True, 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
```

The iteration count for example:

[image: CollatzFractal02 iter]

Comment: Only slightly slower: `DensityPlot[Log[1 + Log[Length[FixedPointList[Function[z, (2 + 7 z - (2 + 5 z) Cos[Pi z])/4], x + I y, 3*^3, SameTest -> (Abs[#2] > 200. &)]]]], {x, 1/3, 5/2}, {y, -1/2, 1/2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow", Sqrt[#]] &), PlotPoints -> 145, PlotRange -> All]`